# In react-native-camera After record async video file is not exist at temp folder

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

To Do First

**Did you try latest release = yes**

**Did you try master = yes**

**Platforms**
-Linux mint

**Versions**

Android: oreo in emulator pixel 2

iOS: n/a

react: "16.9.0",

react-native: "0.61.5",

react-native-camera: "^3.23.1",

**Description/Current Behaviour**

i want record video with rn camera with below code

```
async startRecording() {

   await this.camera.recordAsync({
      maxDuration: 30,
    }).then(data => {
      console.log('data of startRecording', data)
      this.saveVideo(data)
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log('catch of startRecording', e)
    })
}
```

**it will return 4 things**

1 uri

2 deviceOrientation

3 videoOrientation

4 isRecordingInterrupted

After that i want to move recorded video file from **below location** to **download dir** location

**Path of recorded video which receive from data.uri**

```
file:///data/user/0/com.videoapp/cache/Camera/b5ba0d8f-07ea-4755-8f7f-a88d5cc7a331.mp4"
```

**My Code for moving file**

```
saveVideo = async (data) => {
   try {
     RNFetchBlob.fs.mv(data.uri, RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir)
       .then((e) => {
         console.log('MSG =>in RNFetchBlob  ', e)
       })
       .catch(e => { console.log('MSG =>in RNFetchBlob  ', e) })
   } catch (e) {
     console.log('MSG => Main Catch', e)
   }
 }
```

**After all this it is throw error =>
Source file at path does not exist**

**Help  Wanted Here**

1 How to save video with react-native-camera at diff file location

**I take reference from below link**

https://medium.com/@masochist.aman/capturing-images-with-react-native-203e24f93eb9

I also save URI in state

```
async startRecording() {
    this.setState({ recording: true });

    await this.camera.recordAsync({
      maxDuration: 30,
    }).then(data => {
      console.log('data of startRecording', data)

      this.setState({
        videoPath: data.uri
      })
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log('catch of startRecording', e)
    })

}
```

**and then =>**

```
<Video
source={{uri:this.state.videoPath}}
style={{height:300,width:300}}
onError={(e)=>{console.log(e)}} <--error say that try to load empty source
/>
```

Comment: did you found the solution for this

Comment: @Shubham Hey please try RNFetchBlob.fs.cp instead of RNFetchBlob.fs.mv in saveVideo method

Comment: thanks for the reply, Will try that

Comment: Is above code work ! did you try.

Comment: I tried but it's working intermittently